Import file size limitation in Testlink
I am trying to import testcase file that is available in xml format. But the Testlink does not let me import the xml file as it says the size limit is 400 kB. In other forums, it is advised to increase the file size in the php configuration. But when I checked the php configuration, it is already 2M (that I assume is 2 MB). I am confused where the Testlink is getting this limitation from and how can I actually increase so that I could import testcase file.
